# exists? method not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check whether the data exists in the database.. If not i should save the data.. I used exists? method like below in the controller..

```
 def party_order_create
   @party_order = PartyOrder.new(party_order_params)
   if not PartyOrder.exists?(@party_order)
   then @party_order.save
     flash[:notice] = "Party Saved Successfully!!!"
     redirect_to :action => "party_order_index"
   else
     flash.now[:notice] = "Party not Saved"
     render "party_order_new"
   end
 end
```

It is not working.. Please kindly correct me..

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  You already have a party order with those attributes?

Comment: when I use valid? method the new value is not getting saved in the database.

Comment: I have modified my answer pls check

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
@party_order=PartyOrder.find_or_create_by(party_order_params)

if @party_order.present?

  // code

else

  // code

end
```

// or try this

```
@party_order=PartyOrder.where(party_order_params)

if @party_order.present?

    flash.now[:notice] = "Party not Saved"

    render "party_order_new"

else

    @party_order=PartyOrder.new(party_order_params)

    if @party_order.save

        flash[:notice] = "Party Saved Successfully!!!"
        redirect_to :action => "party_order_index"
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you.. It worked for me. but it is redirecting to the party_order_index and showing the flash as party saved successfully.. how could I change that??

Comment: Hi @kelvin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote as well. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if @party_order.present?
```

instead of:

```
if PartyOrder.exists?(@party_order)
```

So it can be rewritten as:

```
def party_order_create
   @party_order=PartyOrder.new(party_order_params)
   @party_order.save
   if @party_order.present? 
     flash[:notice] = "Party Saved Successfully!!!"
     redirect_to :action => "party_order_index"
   else
     flash.now[:notice] = "Party not Saved"
     render "party_order_new"
   end
 end
```

Comment: I am getting the following error..                                                                                                    undefined method `exists?' for #<PartyOrder:0xb4765c3c>

Comment: Please use 'valid?' or 'present?' instead of 'exists?'. Please try the edited code.

Comment: Sorry.. It is not throwing any error.. But the existing values also getting stored.. It is not checking.. I hope so., Please help me with changes.. I am sorry If my problem irritates u.. I am new to Rails..

Comment: Oh i just understood your requirement. The answer given by Dias will solve it i think. And your problem don't irritate me :)

Comment: But thanks for your help @Akshay. It helped me to learn about valid? method. Thank You